# MediaRecorder source uplink records both sides

Tags: android, mediarecorder, audiorecord

I am recording voice from uplink and downlink with the below code but it makes no effect as it is always recording from both sources. I also tried it with AudioRecord but it is also recording both sources. I want to record only one side at a time. And i tested it on more of the devices but no results.

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
```

for uplink :

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK);
   recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
   recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
```

for downlink

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK);
   recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
   recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think you'll find that the behavior of this use-case varies between different phones. Some phones might not make a distinction between `VOICE_CALL` and `VOICE_UPLINK/DOWNLINK`. Others might allow you to record the downlink separately, but not the uplink (probably with the reasoning that they feel you could just record from the `MIC` source instead). I'm pretty sure that this works as you would expect on the XPeria P/U, since I'm the one who originally implemented this in the Gingerbread SW for those phones. Things might've changed on ICS, though.

Comment: Michael ok i got the point you explained here also when i tested it on the phones i got the different results and Michael can you tell on mic how to increase the sound of oponent's voice.